# How to process foreach with multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, csv, kotlin, foreach

**Is it possible to process my forEach with multithreading?** Cause it's a little bit hard to read file with 3 million lines. Maybe somebody have a good knowledge in Kotlin multithreading. Thank you in advance

```
        var records = arrayListOf<myClass>()

        var mapper = CsvMapper()
        mapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.WRAP_AS_ARRAY)
        var csvFile = File("myCsv.csv")
        val response = mapper.readerFor(Array<String>::class.java).readValues<Array<String>>(csvFile)

        response.forEach { line ->
                records.add(
                        myClass(
                                id = line[0],
                                name = line[1],
                                secondName= line[2],

                        )
                )
            }

        return records
```

Comment: Perhaps make this who method a suspend function and trigger it from with a coroutine scope, giving either a custom dispatcher or the default...

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Arrays.stream(response).parallel().forEach(...)
```

Don't forget. You're now in multithreading modus and adding elements to a list.
Make sure, that records is Threadsafe. If it is not yet use

```
Collections.synchronizedList(records);
```

EDIT:

Even better, you could use the

```
map(l -> myClass(id = l[0], name = l[1], secondName = l[2])).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then you do not even have to create a list. Just an idea ...

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to use Arrays.stream with my response. Because response is a MappingIterator<Array<String>>. I am looking for solution with thread or coroutines (unfortunately I'm not experienced with that). But thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: Well, actually i didn't know exactly the type of response. My fault. But i'm not sure if there is a parallel MappingIterator out of the box. The worst case would be, that you have to write your own. At least until now i don't know about it, but i'm interested into it as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some ways to basically achieve this using Coroutines.

```
//Example 1: Suspend Function
suspend fun loadFiles(): List<YourType> {
    var records = arrayListOf<YourType>()
    var mapper = CsvMapper()
    mapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.WRAP_AS_ARRAY)
    var csvFile = File("myCsv.csv")
    val response = mapper.readerFor().readValues(csvFile)

    response.forEach { line ->
        records.add(
            yourType(
                id = line[0],
                name = line[1],
                secondName = line[2]
            )
        )
    }
    return records
}

//Example 2 Using Flows
suspend fun loadFilesWithFlow(): Flow<YourType> {
    return flow {
        var mapper = CsvMapper()
        mapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.WRAP_AS_ARRAY)
        var csvFile = File("myCsv.csv")
        val response = mapper.readerFor(csvFile)

        response.forEach { line ->
            emit(YourType(id = line[0], name = line[1], secondName = line[2]))
        }
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    //You can use the Default Dispatcher or Create you own thread
    /*
    * However the default dispatcher sends the job to a separate thread 
    * that isn't the main thread. By default the max number of thread 
    * available using Default dispatcher is equal to the number of CPU 
    * cores, most likely it's at-least 2 
    */
    //val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default);
    //Example 1
    launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        val records = loadFiles()
    }
    //Example 2: using Flows with custom CoroutineContext(ThreadPool)
    launch(newFixedThreadPoolContext(3, "my-default-thread")) {
        loadFilesWithFlow().collect { yourType ->
            //Do something with your data here
        }
    }
}
```

You can try out with this since you are still basically new to coroutines and threads.